# Recommended USB 3.0 PCI/PCIX adapter for older Dell

Tags: usb, dell-poweredge

Can anyone recommend a USB 3.0 adapter for my older Dell server?  It does not have PCI express (PCIe) so I was looking for PCI or PCIX.  I have been burned in the past installing "desktop" class drives on servers (i.e. blue screens under heavy load) so I would rather pay more to get something reliable.

We are hoping to get better speed on our backups to an external drive, even 10% improvement would be worth it.

Comment: What is the model of the Dell server you are running?

Comment: It's a dell poweredge 1750.

Answer (score 1):

Addonics have released a PCI USB 3.0 card.